# Find Next if OK VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

How do I go to the next cell in a column if the identical cell is not in the date range I am looking for?

For example:

```
   PROJECT           Start Date  End Date    Conflict?
 1. STACK            1/3/2020    1/20/2020
 2. OVERFLOW         5/6/2020    6/1/2020
 3. STACK            2/18/2020   3/4/2020
 4. STACK            3/9/2020    3/11/2020
 5. OVERFLOW         1/5/2020    1/15/2020
```

There are projects, and project names "STACK" and "OVERFLOW", these projects have different start and end dates.

If two different project names cannot start at the same date range. Therefore, STACK cannot start within the same date range as OVERFLOW.

If I were to run my code, it would take STACK and look at the OVERFLOW project in the next row. Obviously, this doesn't start in the same date range, but it will say "OK" in the conflict cell anyway. What I am trying to do is for the code to iterate through the entire column to find a "CONFLICT" (which is when the projects are in the same date range), and if there is no "CONFLICT" then it will say "OK".

I have provided my code down below:

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub TEST()


    Dim FoundCell As Range

    Dim FoundCell1 As Range
    Dim FoundCell2 As Range

    Dim Subst As String
    Dim StartD As Date
    Dim EndD As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Long

    Dim Conflict1 As String
    Dim Conflict2 As String

    Dim StartRef1 As Date
    Dim EndRef1 As Date


    'set a counter for k - which is looping through each column
    Dim LastRow  As Long

    LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For k = 8 To LastRow

        Subst = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & k).Value
    
        Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("B:B").Find(What:=Subst)
        i = FoundCell.Row
        
        'Retrieve both start and stop dates of substation
        StartD = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & k).Value
        EndD = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & k).Value


        'Get the conflict value (in this case would be "STACK" or "OVERFLOW")
        Conflict1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("G" & i).Value
        Conflict2 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("H" & i).Value
  
        'If the Conflict1 is not blank
        If Conflict1 <> "" Then
            
            'Find the Conflict1 in the Master Sheet
            Set FoundCell1 = Sheets("Master").Range("E8:E" & LastRow).Find(What:=Conflict1)
                
            'If not blank then
            If Not FoundCell1 Is Nothing Then
                
                'Get Start and End dates of Conflict1
                StartRef1 = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & FoundCell1.Row).Value
                EndRef1 = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & FoundCell1.Row).Value
                
                'If the Start and Stop Conflict dates match with the Substation dates, then CONFLICT
                If (StartD >= StartRef1 And StartD <= EndRef1) And (EndD >= StartRef1 And EndD <= EndRef1) Then
                    Sheets("Master").Range("AS" & k).Value = "CONFLICT " & Conflict1 & " at E" & FoundCell1.Row
                Else
                    Sheets("Master").Range("AS" & k).Value = "OK"
                    If Sheets("Master").Range("AS" & k).Value = "OK" Then
                        Set FoundCell1 = Sheets("Master").Range("E:E").FindNext(FoundCell1)
                    End If
                End If
                       
            End If
        End If
                            
                            
        If Conflict2 <> "" Then
            Set FoundCell2 = Sheets("Master").Range("E8:E" & LastRow).Find(What:=Conflict2)
            
            If Not FoundCell2 Is Nothing Then
                StartRef1 = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & FoundCell2.Row).Value
                EndRef1 = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & FoundCell2.Row).Value
                
                If (StartD >= StartRef1 And StartD <= EndRef1) And (EndD >= StartRef1 And EndD <= EndRef1) Then
                    Sheets("Master").Range("AT" & k).Value = "CONFLICT " & Conflict2 & " at E" & FoundCell2.Row
                Else
                    Sheets("Master").Range("AT" & k).Value = "OK"
                       
                End If
            End If
        End If
                    
  
        'increment k to go through the entire column
    Next k
      
                        
End Sub
```

EDIT** : Here is a better explanation and example:

Hi, I am trying to determine how to look for the next Duplicate in the list if there is no conflict in the date range.

Here is an example I have made. This sheet has the subject and the conflicting subjects. This means that the specific subject cannot be within the same date range as the conflicting subjects. Therefore, this is mostly a key for us to refer to.

```
Subject   Conflict1       Conflict2       Conflict3
Library     PE      
PE         SocialS      
SocialS    Science          Library         Reading
Science     Math            Reading 
Math        PE      
Reading     Library          SocialS
```

This is the sheet that I need to add code to and having some issues with. Currently, my code only looks at the first possible conflicting subject (the subject that is referred in the key and cannot be within the same date range) and determines whether it is OK, or if it is CONFLICT at A*.

```
      A             B          C            D           E           F
1    Subject       Start      End       Conflict1   Conflict2   Conflict3
2    Library       1/13/20   1/13/20                
3    SocialS       1/13/20   1/13/20                
4    Science       1/13/20   3/24/20                
5    PE            1/21/20   3/12/20                
6    SocialS       3/3/20    3/26/20                
7    PE            3/16/20   3/26/20                
8    SocialS       3/17/20   3/18/20                
9    Science       3/25/20   3/26/20                
10    Math         4/6/20    5/11/20                
11    Math         4/6/20    4/10/20                
12    Math         4/13/20   4/22/20                
13    Math         4/23/20   5/11/20                
14    Reading      5/13/20   5/15/20                
15    Library      5/13/20   5/14/20                
16    Science      5/18/20   12/3/20                
17    Science      5/18/20   9/25/20                
18    SocialS      5/18/20   7/2/20             
19    Reading      6/1/20    6/1/20             
20    Math         6/1/20    6/26/20                
21    Reading      6/15/20   4/29/21                
22    Reading      11/1/19   1/31/20                
23    Reading      6/15/20   6/18/20                
24    Reading      6/22/20   8/13/20                
25    Science      7/1/20    7/1/20             
26    PE           7/1/20    7/2/20             
27    PE           7/8/20    7/8/20             
28    Library      7/13/20   7/24/20                
29    SocialS      7/13/20   7/17/20
```

For example, if we take a look at the first subject at A2, which is Library. Now, the code would then go to the other sheet, the key, and look for Library. It will then look at Conflict1, Conflict2, and Conflict3. It sees that Library has a conflict with PE. So, now it will go back to the main sheet and look for PE. The code will go to A5, and checks the Date Range B2 to C2, and B5 to C5. It is clearly not in the same date range, so it will say "Ok at A5" in the column E2 to match up with the key. The issue is, that the code then finishes executing for that row, and now it will go to A3 sees that there is SocialS, and look in the Key to find the Conflict1, Conflict2, and Conflict3. It does not go find the next PE for Library, but instead it finishes and starts over for a new subject instead.

Also, this list has most that are in ascending date order which is unintentional so please don't include that since this list is about 499 rows long and the other dates are not in order.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Conflicts()

Dim Trans As String

Dim Conflict1 As String
Dim Conflict2 As String
Dim Conflict3 As String

Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FoundCell1 As Range
Dim FoundCell2 As Range
Dim FoundCell3 As Range

Dim k As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim StartD As Date
Dim EndD As Date
Dim StartRef As Date
Dim EndRef As Date

LastRow = Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 2 To LastRow

    Subj = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & k).Value
    
        Set FoundCell = Sheets("Key").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Subj)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        i = FoundCell.Row
        
        'Retrieve both start and stop dates of substation
        StartD = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & k).Value
        EndD = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & k).Value
        
        Conflict1 = Sheets("Key").Range("J" & i).Value
        Conflict2 = Sheets("Key").Range("K" & i).Value
        Conflict3 = Sheets("Key").Range("L" & i).Value
        
    
        If Conflict1 <> "" Then
            Set FoundCell1 = Sheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Find(What:=Conflict1)
            If Not FoundCell1 Is Nothing Then
                StartRef = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & FoundCell1.Row).Value
                EndRef = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & FoundCell1.Row).Value
                 If (StartD >= StartRef And StartD <= EndRef) And (EndD >= StartRef And EndD <= EndRef) Then
                    Sheets("Master").Range("D" & k).Value = "CONFLICT " & Conflict1 & " at D" & FoundCell1.Row
                     Else
                       Sheets("Master").Range("D" & k).Value = "OK"
                       
                       End If
                        End If
                        End If
                        
                        
        If Conflict2 <> "" Then
            Set FoundCell2 = Sheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Find(What:=Conflict2)
            If Not FoundCell2 Is Nothing Then
                StartRef = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & FoundCell2.Row).Value
                EndRef = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & FoundCell2.Row).Value
                
                 If (StartD >= StartRef And StartD <= EndRef) And (EndD >= StartRef And EndD <= EndRef) Then
                    Sheets("Master").Range("E" & k).Value = "CONFLICT " & Conflict2 & " at D" & FoundCell2.Row
                     Else
                       Sheets("Master").Range("E" & k).Value = "OK"
                       
                       End If
                        End If
                        End If
                        
                        
        If Conflict3 <> "" Then
            Set FoundCell3 = Sheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Find(What:=Conflict3)
            If Not FoundCell3 Is Nothing Then
                StartRef = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & FoundCell3.Row).Value
                EndRef = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & FoundCell3.Row).Value
                
                 If (StartD >= StartRef And StartD <= EndRef) And (EndD >= StartRef And EndD <= EndRef) Then
                    Sheets("Master").Range("F" & k).Value = "CONFLICT " & Conflict3 & " at D" & FoundCell3.Row
                     Else
                       Sheets("Master").Range("F" & k).Value = "OK"
                       
                       End If
                        End If
                        End If
                        
  
                                                
            End If
Next k


End Sub
```

Comment: Can projects with the same name have overlapping dates? Is the only conflict in your (limited) example between projects 1 and 5, if so which project line is labelled as "CONFLICT" (should it be both of them with an indicator for which project line(s) are in conflict)?

Comment: Yes, there can be overlapping dates if the project is the same name. @PeterT

Comment: Considering you didn't want to include the year in your other posts, I believe this leads to the complex check... but that can be built from the simple:  `Countifs()` may be the simplest solution.  If <> my name & if those dates are lower than my date.  If it counts, you have a conflict.  This gets more complicated when you exclude year, but just like the other post, you can utilize a date serial where you have a fixed year when comparing the day/month.

Comment: @Cyril Actually, in this case, this WILL be checking the entire date, which includes the year. Would you mind including an example of how I could implement the Countifs in my code?

Comment: @Cyril, I included a better explanation and example of what I meant. So sorry for the misunderstanding again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by your description that Stack and Overflow cannot be in conflict but Stack and Stack can be in same period.

Also i would suggest to Disable `ScreenUpdates` and `AutomaticCalculations`

I Create a class `Project`

```
Public ID           As Long
Public Project      As String
Public StartDate    As Date
Public EndDate      As Date
Public Conflict     As String
```

And the code

```
Public Sub Sort()
Dim Proj            As Project
Dim MainProj        As Project
Dim Projects        As Collection
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim i               As Long
Dim j               As Long
'You can do lastrow, or do while loop until empty cell etc.
'Im doing offset that why im extracting one from results
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Create a collection of items to save them
Set Projects = New Collection

'Create a collection
For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
    Set Proj = New Project
    Proj.ID = i
    Proj.Project = Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)
    Proj.StartDate = Range("B1").Offset(i, 0)
    Proj.EndDate = Range("C1").Offset(i, 0)
    Projects.Add Proj
Next i

'Itearete and check collection
For i = 1 To Projects.Count
    Set MainProj = Projects(i)
    'Second loop doeasnt need to start before current index
    For j = i + 1 To Projects.Count
        Set Proj = Projects(j)
        'Do not compare same projects
        If MainProj.Project <> Proj.Project Then
            'Check if in range
            If (MainProj.StartDate <= Proj.EndDate) _
            And (Proj.StartDate <= MainProj.EndDate) Then
                MainProj.Conflict = "Conflict"
                Proj.Conflict = "Conflict"
            ElseIf MainProj.Conflict <> "Conflict" Then
                MainProj.Conflict = "Ok"
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'write down data
For Each Proj In Projects
    Range("D1").Offset(Proj.ID, 0) = Proj.Conflict
Next Proj
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved via a formula, checking where:

- The name is different
- If the start date < end dates
- If the end date > start dates

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$6,"<>"&A2,B$2:B$6,"<"&C2,C$2:C$6,">"&B2)
```

The first and last have an overlap and provide a conflict:
[image]

You can wrap the `countifs()` in an `if`-statement to output desired results, e.g.:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$6,"<>"&A2,B$2:B$6,"<"&C2,C$2:C$6,">"&B2)>0,"Conflict!","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. As this is a good solution for the example I have presented, it won't do great for what I am trying to implement, since there are multiple duplicates with 500+ projects. Is there a way to do VBA instead? @Cyril

Comment: @vnt you can always add the formula across your ranges with VBA

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but there are also certain project names that it will compare to as well. It shouldn't compare to all projects that have different names. For example, let's say there are project names Math, Science, and Reading. Science will check whether there are any conflicts with Reading not Math. @Cyril