# Checking Date Conflicts VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, date-range

I need some help trying to figure out why this code is working the way it is. There are dates where it would say that there is a conflict when it shouldn't be. It would be great it I could have some help on this. I am relatively new to VBA and it is taking me a long time to think of a solution to this issue I am having.

The way the code should work is that if the date is in any of the two date ranges, then it would say "OK" OR if it says "Anytime" then it would also say "OK" because that would mean that the project can start at anytime. However, if the date is not within the range of any of the two date ranges given, then it would say "CONFLICT".

For example, if the date is within 8/1/2022 - 8/30/2022 or if it isnt in these dates, it would compare to the second date range 9/2/2022 - 9/20/2022 for example. The date has to fall into one of these in order to be "OK" if not then it is "CONFLICT"

```
Sub OutageWindow()
'
'This is testing the outage window conflict
'

Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim Subst As String
Dim StartD As String
Dim EndD As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Long

Dim StartRef1 As String
Dim EndRef1 As String

Dim StartRef2 As String
Dim EndRef2 As String

'set a counter for k - which is loopng through each column
Dim LastRow  As Long

LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 8 To LastRow

   
'get the cell value
Subst = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & k).Value

StartD = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & k).Value
EndD = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & k).Value

'Set the Range as Col B from the reference sheet and find the Str
Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("B:B").Find(What:=Subst)

'initialize Integer i as the row number to locate (more for debugging purpose to see if it is accurate)
i = FoundCell.Row


StartRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("C" & i).Value
EndRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("D" & i).Value

StartRef2 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("E" & i).Value
EndRef2 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("F" & i).Value




'If the found cell is not empty, then print message in a column of Master sheet
If FoundCell.Row <> 100 Then
    
   If StartRef1 = "Anytime" And StartRef2 = "Anytime" Then
        Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
        Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
         
            
   
        'If the start date is within the reference dates then "OK"
       ElseIf (StartD >= StartRef1 And StartD <= EndRef1) And (EndD >= StartRef1 And EndD <= EndRef1) Then
            Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
            Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
          
               
                
                 'If the project lasts more than (15) 20 weeks AND if the Conflict was "OK" (Not including "Anytime" time frames), then highlight yellow and print "CHECK" instead
        If Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK" Then
             If DateDiff("ww", StartD, EndD) > 20 Then
                Sheets("Master").Range("BF" & k).Value = "The Project would last " & DateDiff("ww", StartD, EndD) & " week(s)"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "CHECK"
            End If
         End If
        
                
             ElseIf (StartD >= StartRef2 And StartD <= EndRef2) And (EndD >= StartRef2 And EndD <= EndRef2) Then
                Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
                Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
                    
                'If not, then provide info why
                ElseIf (StartD < StartRef1 Or StartD > EndRef1) And (EndD < StartRef1 Or EndD > EndRef1) Then
                Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "CONFLICT"
                   Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " to " & EndD & " Not in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
        
         ElseIf (StartD < StartRef2 Or StartD > EndRef2) And (EndD < StartRef2 Or EndD > EndRef2) Then
                Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "CONFLICT"
                    Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " to " & EndD & " Not in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
        End If

    'Provide location of col and row from reference sheet
        Sheets("Master").Range("BE" & k).Value = "The Subst " & Subst & " at B" & i
        Sheets("Master").Range("I" & k).Value = Round(DateDiff("D", StartD, EndD) / 7, 1) & " wks"
        
    End If
'increment k to go through the entire column
Next k
                       
                                     
End Sub
```

**EDIT: Here is an update on my code which gave the same output:

```
Sub OutageWindow()
'
'This is testing the outage window conflict
'

Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim Subst As String
Dim StartD As Variant
Dim EndD As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Long



'set a counter for k - which is loopng through each column
Dim LastRow  As Long

LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 8 To LastRow

   
'get the cell value
Subst = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & k).Value

StartD = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & k).Value
EndD = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & k).Value

'Set the Range as Col B from the reference sheet and find the Str
Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("B:B").Find(What:=Subst)

'initialize Integer i as the row number to locate (more for debugging purpose to see if it is accurate)
i = FoundCell.Row

Dim StartRef1 As Variant: StartRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("C" & i).Value
Dim EndRef1 As Variant: EndRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("D" & i).Value

Dim StartRef2 As Variant: StartRef2 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("E" & i).Value
Dim EndRef2 As Variant: EndRef2 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("F" & i).Value


'If the found cell is not empty, then print message in a column of Master sheet
If FoundCell.Row <> 100 Then
    
Select Case True
    Case IsDate(StartRef1)
        Select Case True
            Case (StartD >= StartRef1 And StartD <= EndRef1) And (EndD >= StartRef1 And EndD <= EndRef1)
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2

                
                Case Else
                   Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "CONFLICT"
                   Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " to " & EndD & " Not in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
           End Select
                
    
    Case IsDate(StartRef2)
        Select Case True
              Case (StartD >= StartRef2 And StartD <= EndRef2) And (EndD >= StartRef2 And EndD <= EndRef2)
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2

                Case Else
                   Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "CONFLICT"
                   Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " to " & EndD & " Not in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
    End Select
    
    
    Case Not IsNumeric(StartRef1)
        Select Case StartRef1
            Case "Anytime"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
            'Case "N/A"
    
        End Select
        
         Case Not IsNumeric(StartRef2)
        Select Case StartRef2
            Case "Anytime"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BB" & k).Value = "OK"
                 Sheets("Master").Range("BC" & k).Value = StartD & " and " & EndD & " in Range of " & StartRef1 & " and " & EndRef1 & " or " & StartRef2 & " and " & EndRef2
            'Case "N/A"
    
        End Select
        End Select
   End If
'increment k to go through the entire column
Next k
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you abandon your previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542825/vba-determine-conflict-or-ok-when-comparing-two-date-ranges#comment129869579_73542825

Comment: Copying comment from previous post: "I would suppose that if your checks make it to the else case, that the previous cases failed. Considering you have references to `startref1` that are each a string and a date/number, I wonder about what is actually being compared... `StartD >= StartRef1` versus `StartRef1 = "Anytime"`"

Comment: Oh I see, Yes I abandoned the other post since I didn't seem to get any help. I don't think this solution has resolved my issue. @Cyril

Comment: Are the dates you're reading actual dates?  Did you declare your `StartRef1` (and all other dates) as `Date` and not as `String` ?

Comment: You don't have any logic to deal with "N/A" either...

Comment: With N/A it doesnt do anything. It is doing what it should be doing when interacting with that string. The issue is that if I declare it as Date, then the Strings "Anytime" and "N/A" will then cause an error. Is there a way to check these Strings as well as checking the dates. Another thing with declaring Date is that it checks the year, which is not what I want @TimWilliams

Comment: OK then it would be useful to show a sample of the input data here, and explain what "N/A" represents, and why you don't want to include the year.  None of that is obvious from your code

Comment: I also tried doing CDate, but that didnt change anything to the excel sheet. @TimWilliams

Comment: Can there be date spans which are not witin the same year (eg. 12/25 to 2/15) ? how do you handle those while ignoring the year?

Comment: @vnt if those separations are causing the same issues, I would have to ask about your data... what is the format?  Are they actually dates?  if they are not, then that would/could lead to issues with flagging appropriately.

Comment: You can also shorten your cases from `Case (StartD >= StartRef2 And StartD <= EndRef2) And (EndD >= StartRef2 And EndD <= EndRef2)` to comparing a low value, a high value, and the test values, such as:  `Case StartD >= StartRef2 And EndD <= EndRef2 And StartD <= EndD`

Comment: Yes, I did do that, but it has made no difference to the output @Cyril

Comment: The data is in two separate columns, one column for the StartD and another for EndD. It is comparing this data to another sheet with two different start and stop dates which are StartRef1, EndRef1, StartRef2, EndRef2. If it isnt in the range of StartRef1 and EndRef1, then compare it in the range of StartRef2 and EndRef2, if it is not in the range of these dates, then there is a CONFLICT. @Cyril

Comment: @vnt specific to your data, I would think that, where you have some "OK" ranges, that the "Conflict" ranges (which should be okay) may not be actual dates, or the dates have years within them and that isn't visually present.  Essentially, if it works for "some" it should work for "all," which indicates that the "all" scenario is not a like-for-like.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I understand what you mean by that. These all are dates, and for example the date reference range is from 4/5/2022 to 6/8/2022, and the project is from 4/5/2022 to 4/5/2022 for example, there are instances where this would be a conflict. Or 4/28/2019 - 6/3/2019 would also be a conflict. Basically, I think that for some reason it is randomized. I have tried debugging and it seems like when checking for the StartRef1 and EndRef1, it would say OK for some, and randomly say Conflict for others where it should actually be ok. @Cyril

Comment: @vnt select your cell and press `Ctrl+1`; the visual of the cell may look like a date, but if it is not formatted as a date, then it's a string... that string may be causing the issue, because it cannot be treated as an *actual* date.  I would step through (`F8` in the module), and see what values are failing when you suspect they should be true.

Comment: I just did that with a few if them, and the entire column has Data Validation on Set as Date. So, I do not think that this is the issue. @Cyril

Comment: @vnt then your next step is to step-through (`F8` in the module) to see exactly what is failing when you believe they should be true.

Comment: If you do have time, would you mind checking my other post as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488251/find-next-if-ok-vba

There is an answer written there and I think potentially could be the solution, but I am relatively new to VBA so I am unsure how to implement it like they have shown. It's causing errors to my code. @Cyril

Comment: I think I have found the issue for why the code you proovided is causing Conflicts when it shouldn't be. It is checking IsDate, and then it is comparing the entire date (with the year included) so that is why there are conflicts. Is there a way to check for the Month and Date only? @Cyril

Comment: @vnt see my edited answer... it uses `month()` & `day()` in conjunction with `dateserial()`, where we fix the year to a single year to circumvent the year item.

Comment: @Cyril Great, thank you! I didn't know about that! Again, if you do get the chance would you mind helping me with my previous post as well? I think it is fairly simple, but it has been taking me a while to find the solution for it. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example of determining what is the format for data in `StartRef1` using `Select` (untested):

```
Dim StartRef1 as Variant:  StartRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("C" & i).Value
Select Case True
    Case IsDate(StartRef1)
        Select Case True
            Case StartD >= StartRef1 And EndD <= EndRef1
                'Do one
            Case Else
                'Do two
        End Select
    Case Not IsNumeric(StartRef1)
        Select Case StartRef1.Value
            Case "Anytime"
                'Do something
            Case "N/A"
                'Do something else
            Case Else
                MsgBox "This is not a date, nor does it contain *Anytime* or *N/A*"
        End Select
End Select
```

Currently, you have `Dim StartRef1 as String:  StartRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("C" & i).Value` which may lead to the inability to compare to numbers/dates, e.g., you fail to determine if `StartD >= StartRef1`.

If you ensure you have a date (`IsDate()`), then you can be able to compare... similarly, you need to ensure that `StartD` and the other variables are of the same type.

---

**Edit1:**

Quick update to show comparison of month/day only, after `IsDate()`, using a fixed year to not take year into account:

```
Dim StartRef1 as Variant:  StartRef1 = Sheets("Sub_Ref_Matrix").Range("C" & i).Value
Select Case True
    Case IsDate(StartRef1)
        Select Case True
            Case DateSerial(1900,Month(StartD),Day(StartD)) >= DateSerial(1900,Month(StartRef1),Day(StartRef1)) And DateSerial(1900,Month(EndD),Day(EndD)) >= DateSerial(1900,Month(EndRef1),Day(EndRef1)) And StartD <= EndD
                'Do one
            Case Else
                'Do two
        End Select
    Case Not IsNumeric(StartRef1)
        Select Case StartRef1.Value
            Case "Anytime"
                'Do something
            Case "N/A"
                'Do something else
            Case Else
                MsgBox "This is not a date, nor does it contain *Anytime* or *N/A*"
        End Select
End Select
```

Comment: @vnt did this aid in resolving your issue?

Comment: Hi I tried implementing what you had similarly, but unfortunately there are still issues. @Cyril

Comment: It looks like it didnt change anything to the spreadsheet, the projects that shouldn't be conflicts are conflicts for some reason.

Comment: @vnt can you update your post to include your new code, not changing your existing code and issues?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply. @Cyril

Comment: @vnt if this resolved this question, please let us know

Comment: Ok, I will definitely let you know. @Cyril